# How to paginate data from a model in a table of ten rows?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I'm getting a large number of rows from a database. Each rows is associated to an object of a model. So now, thanks to a strongly typed view whiere I'm passing a list of objects like that :

```
 public PartialViewResult ListerIncidentsHotline()
    {
        int NumDossier = StructureData.DonneNumDossier((string)Session["Utilisateur"], (string)Session["MotDePasse"]);
        List<IncidentHotline> ListeIncidents = StructureData.DonneIncidentsHotline(NumDossier, 10);
        int NbreIncidents = StructureData.DonneNombreIncidents(NumDossier);
        ViewBag.NombreIncidents = NbreIncidents;
        return this.PartialView(ListeIncidents);
    }
```

So in the view I'm displaying a table with the datas like that :

```
 <table id="tabIncident" class="table table-striped">
    <th>IdIncident</th><th>Libelle</th><th>Motif</th><th>Nom du responsable</th><th>Date de création</th><th>Date de clôture</th>
    @foreach (var Incident in Model)
    {  
        <tr><td>@Incident.IdIncident</td><td>@Incident.LibelleIncident</td><td>@Incident.MotifIncident</td><td>@Incident.NomResponsable</td><td>@Incident.DateCreation</td><td>@Incident.DateCloture</td></tr>
    }
</table>
```

but now I would like juste to display 10 of these rows in the table and then, by a click on a button, display the ten next lines instead. Does somebody has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function could look like this:

```
public PartialViewResult ListerIncidentsHotline(int page = 1)
```

It's a little trickier doing paging with a partial view.  Essentially your parent view needs to also have a parameter for the page number and it needs to pass that information on to the partial view.

Then you probably want to change your Model.  Right now your Model is itself an IEnumerable of  your domain model.  You want a model that contains this IEnumerable, but also has pagination information such as the total number of pages and the current page.

So your model would look like:

```
public class IncidentPageInfo
{
    public int NumPages { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }
}
```

Then when returning the View you would pass this object as your model and you would populate the page like the following:

```
public PartialViewResult ListerIncidentsHotline(int page = 1)
{
    // other code

    const int PageSize = 10;

    IEnumerable<Incident> incidents; // this is returned from your data persistence.  IQueryable is preferred to IEnumerable

    var viewModel = new IncidentPageInfo()
    {
        NumPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)incidents.Count() / PageSize),
        CurrentPage = page,
        PageSize = PageSize,
        Incidents = incidents.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),
    };

    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really interesting, it shows me also how to solve some others problems. It's great !

Answer (score 0):

The eseaist way is just to use pagination library. There are a lot of them in Nuget, but most popular seems to be [PagedList](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/). Read [here](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) how to implement.